# why my code is working as line 21 scanf function is getting executed before the line 18 printf function?

Tags: arrays, printf, scanf, buffer

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int num, i, n, a;
    
    printf("Enter total numbers of integers you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nEnter the numbers in the array : ");
    int arr[n];

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d ",&arr[i]);
    }

   

    
    printf("\n\n\nNow enter the number to searched in the array :");


    scanf("%d", &num);

    for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
        a = arr[j];
        if(a == num)
        {
            printf("Your position for the number %d in the array is : %d",num, j+1);
            break;
        }
        else 
            continue;
    }
    if( a!= num){
        printf("Number not found!");
    }
    
}
```

Why is my code not working line by line, when my printf is written before scanf.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the extra space in scanf which was used in for loop to take input.

Because of that space compiler is looking for input and skipping your print statement and directly jumping to another line.

Please use the below snippet.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    int num, i, n, a;
    
    printf("Enter total numbers of integers you want to enter: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    printf("\nEnter the numbers in the array : ");
    int arr[n];

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++){
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
    }
    printf("Now enter the number to searched in the array :");
    scanf("%d", &num);

    for(int j = 0; j<n; j++){
        a = arr[j];
        if(a == num)
        {
            printf("Your position for the number %d in the array is : %d",num, j+1);
            break;
        }
        else 
            continue;
    }
    if( a!= num){
        printf("Number not found!");
    }
}
```

Please find my below output from my system.

[image: code from my compiler]

Comment: it is not working.... just copy and run on your compiler...do it & then you will understand the problem

Comment: Hi Shivam just remove \n\n\n in printf Statement as shown above..

Comment: are i removed it, i have done all the things.... if you just copy my code on your code editor...and run it you will understand....it still not working.

Comment: Shivam please check my  output attached in answer. it might be helpful.